# SQL: updating a column in one table based on a count result from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I've got a table called `GUEST` and a table called `HOTEL_BOOKING`.

I want to update a column in the `GUEST` table called `guest_nobookings` (this is the number of bookings a guest has made at the hotel).

I can get the number of bookings a guest has made from the `HOTEL_BOOKING` table by performing a count on the hotel booking number based on the guest number.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(hotel_bookingno) 
  FROM hotel_booking 
 GROUP BY guest_no;
```

That gives me the number of bookings for each guest who has stayed at the hotel. To update the GUEST table I've tried this:

```
UPDATE guest 
   SET (guest_nobookings = (SELECT COUNT(hotel_bookingno) 
                              FROM hotel_booking 
                             GROUP BY guest_no));
```

I get a 'single-row subquery returns more than one row' error when I try this however.

Is there a more direct way of solving this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a correlated subquery to update here:

```
UPDATE guest g
SET guest_nobookings = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hotel_booking hb
                        WHERE hb.guest_no = g.hotel_bookingno);
```

You may need to alter the above slightly to make it work.  As a side note, you might want to rethink your design and avoid even doing this update.  The reason is that each time the state in the `hotel_booking` table changes, the count aggregates might become invalid, and would have to recomputed.  In general, we try to avoid storing aggregates of original data in SQL.

Comment: The `GROUP BY` is unnecessary and confusing in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to have sane data in two tables? It will lead to inconsitent data in one of them. (As already described by Tim)

My suggestion is to use the `view` for all details of the `guest` and in the view use count from `hotel_bookings` table.

If you really want to update the count then You can use `merge` statement as following:

```
Merge into guest g
Using (select COUNT(*) as cnt, hb.guest_no
FROM hotel_booking hb 
GROUP BY hb.guest_no) hb
On (hb.guest_no = g.hotel_bookingno)
When matched then 
Update set g.guest_nobookings = hb.cnt;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE guest  
SET guest_nobookings = (  
       WITH t1 AS (  
                    SELECT COUNT(*) no_bk, guest_no  FROM  hotel_booking  
                    GROUP BY hotel_booking.guest_no  
                  )  
       SELECT no_bk FROM t1  
       WHERE guest_no = guest.hotel_bookingno  
   );
```

This is another way to update the table using WITH clause.